# textview.settext text has many replacementspans on android 10 occured ANR

Tags: android, textview, android-anr-dialog

It takes a lot of time in `view.onMeasure` when textview set text(spannable) has many ReplacementSpans on android 10 phone, so it is occurred ANR.

I tested on Samsung G981N and G975N phones(android 10)

According to android profiler, `android.graphics.text.LineBreaker.nComputeLineBreaks` runs most of running times.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtHqV.png) the image, and below the code I tested.

(compileSdkVersion 29)

(replace A*100 to K*2 using ReplacementSpan)

(textLength = 3000 runs normally, but 30000 occurred ANR)

```
private fun test() {
    val text = StringBuffer()
    val textLength = 30000
    val spanLength = 100

    var count = 0
    while (count < textLength) {
        text.append("A")
        count++
    }

    val spannable = text.toSpannable()

    var index = 0
    while (index < (textLength / spanLength)) {
        val span = TestReplacementSpan()
        spannable.setSpan(span, index * spanLength, index * spanLength + spanLength, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        index++
    }

    binding.textview.text = spannable
}

class TestReplacementSpan : ReplacementSpan() {
    private val replaceText = "KK"

    override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, fm: FontMetricsInt?): Int {
        if (fm != null) {
            paint.getFontMetricsInt(fm)
        }
       return Math.round(paint.measureText(replaceText, 0, replaceText.length))
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, x: Float, top: Int, y: Int, bottom: Int, paint: Paint) {
        canvas.drawText(replaceText, 0, replaceText.length, Math.max(x, 0f), y.toFloat(), paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the use case? You will want to break it up to separate paragraphs and feed it to RecyclerView or something like that. There's no way 30000 characters would fit on my phone screen so there's no need to try and measure and draw it all at once (plus the fact that it takes too much time). **Break it up**. Perhaps even prepare the spannables on a worker thread (or in parallel) before sending them to UI.

Answer (score 0):

add below code and it is solved

```
textview.breakStrategy = Layout.BREAK_STRATEGY_SIMPLE
```